# Content pane of users related to node by field using panels, views (D7)

Tags: views, users, panels

I've created a Content Type of Service Page which is the same as a Basic Page.

I added a new field to Users called service_type and then added this field to Service Page. I set the service_type in both Users and Service Pages appropriately. When a Service Page is displayed I would like a list of the Users with the same service_type to appear below it.

I thought this would be a perfect place for Panels and Views so I made a Content Pane of Users:

Argument Input -> From context -> service_type

Contextual Filter -> Field: service_type

I added this Content Pane to my Panels Node and set Field: service_type to Node being viewed.

Doesn't work though; in fact, nothing appears. If I delete the Contextual Filter I do however get the full list of users, so clearly this is where the problem must be.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Views 7.x-3.1, Panels 7.x-3.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the display fields section for my Content Type I had service_type hidden (because I only wanted to use it to filter Users without having to use a vocabulary), as such it wasn't featuring in the context and wasn't being passed into my View Content Pane.

I had to leave it displayed, then create a custom display for 'Full Content' and hide the field there instead.